# Copy or don't copy extra variables in PHP?

Tags: php, performance, optimization

Reading the [Google Developers PHP performance tips](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-php) I saw that it isn't recommended to make an extra copy of a varible.

Instead of this:

```
$description = strip_tags($_POST['description']);
echo $description;
```

It recommends this:

```
echo strip_tags($_POST['description']);
```

The reason is a possible unnecessary consumption of memory.

But doing some searches I saw some rebuttals saing that PHP implements “copy-on-write” memory management. This basically means that we can assign a value to as many variables as we like without having to worry about the data actually being copied.

So I would like to know if in more complex situations, where for example `$_POST` or `$_GET` variables will be used in many places of the code, whether it is better practice to use or not use extra variables, considering these criteria:

1) Security

2) Maintenance / Readability

3) Performance

**EDIT 1**

I will use the below example to better ilustrate the question.

Is it better this kind code (Considering the criteria above):

```
$user = anti_injection($_POST['user']);
$pass = anti_injection($_POST['pass']);

// Continue the code using $user and $pass
```

Or this?

```
$_POST['user'] = anti_injection($_POST['user']);
$_POST['pass'] = anti_injection($_POST['pass']);

// Continue the code using $_POST['user'] and $_POST['pass']
```

Comment: Not a good question; the answer would be: it depends. PHP in fact create just a reference and increases the ref-count in the first case. If you do not re-use the stripped variable in your example then you will use the second snippet; if you need it more than one time without tags, you'll use the second snippet.

Comment: That kind of performance issue only matters on a Google scale. For everyone else, assign as many variables as make your life easier.

Comment: +1 to Matchu - as somebody put it here earlier: if this type of performance matters to you, then you should not be using PHP. These are really fast operations, we are talking nano-seconds here

Comment: @feeela, Sorry, but i think it is a good question. Can be a easy thing for you, but it will help others programmers who are not sure about it yet. By the way, have you suggested to use always the second snippet?

Comment: @Matchu, I am worried with security and maintenance too, not only with performance, after all, if you are working in a project with more than one programmer, good practices are always required.

Comment: @KSiimson, Sorry, but i disagree. A large project as the Facebook uses PHP and i am sure that they took care with this kind of detail.

Comment: @Marcio Simao: Yes and no. Yes, they would still use PHP, but no, they would not worry about whether to assign a variable or not. Instead, they translate PHP into C++ and then pre-compile it (check out HipHop for PHP). As for the issue, whatever is more readable is considered better.

Comment: @KSiimson, Before translate they use PHP, so `$_POST` and `$_GET` variables are received by PHP, because of this i continue believing that they take care about this kind of thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP's "lazy copy" only applies to arrays. The array's data is only duplicated if one copy of the array is changed, which is why it's okay for the `foreach` loop to work on a copy of the original array, for instance.

Objects are passed by reference, even when not told to do so with `&`. Example:

```
$a = new StdClass();
$b = $a;
$b->derp = "foo";
var_dump($a->derp); // "foo"
```

Resources are references to a resource to be used by a particular extension, so they can't meaningfully be copied.

Everything else is copied directly.

---

Unnecessary variables should be avoided anyway. For instance, instead of:

```
$step1 = 123;
$step2 = $step1 * 4;
$step3 = $step2 + 99;
$step4 = $step3 / 3;
echo $step4;
```

You could just write:

```
echo (123*4+99)/3;
```

(or, in this case, just `echo 197;`)

The point is, unnexessary variables do create clutter and could potentially conflict with a variable you defined elsewhere.

Comment: Very good your answer! I've done an update, please tell me your opinion considering the EDIT 1.

Comment: I'd say the latter is a better solution, but bearing in mind that your strings will probably only be about 30 bytes long, you won't be gaining much.

Comment: Re: lazy copy only applies to arrays, this page asserts otherwise:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php -- "PHP is smart enough not to copy the actual variable container when it is not necessary. Variable containers get destroyed when the "refcount" reaches zero."

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need a "copy" of $description, the clearer approach is definitely:

```
echo strip_tags($_POST['description']);
```

Regarding performance, as you said it, PHP will still create a resulting value in memory and assign it to a Z_Data structure thus still consuming memory. So it's not faster or less memory intensive to use the first or the second methods.

Finaly, security has nothing to do with memory consumption but you need to remember how to clean your output correctly. Using strip-tags is fine, adding slashes is another good way to prevent hackers from using XSS injection.

Also note, regarding your Copy-on-write, if you do this:

```
$description = 'Hello-world';
$trimmed_description = str_replace('-', ' ', $description);
$escaped = htmlentities($trimmed_description);
echo $escaped;
```

instead of

```
echo htmlentities(str_replace('-', ' ', 'Hello-world'));
```

The later will obviously save you memory... very little in this case, but you will still save some...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helps me to clarify some points. I've done an update, can you please tell me your opinion considering the EDIT 1.

Comment: Scneario #2 will be better as you will replace the data inside $_POST and thus the reference count in the Z_DATA pointed by these will be dropped to 0 and discarded.