# PHP - to copy, or not to copy, that is the variable?

Tags: php, performance, variables, copy

I landed up on this link: https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-php

And then did a search about variable copies and found this: [Copy or don't copy extra variables in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417010/copy-or-dont-copy-extra-variables-in-php)

So I understand the above concepts but to my understanding the below code is actually good practice but sorta goes against the don't copy statement. Its almost like "don't copy" must have a condition. Ive always understood that doing a function call on every loop is more resource intensive than storing (copy).

```
$total = total();
for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++){
}
```

Same applies for (best example I could think of using Google's example):

```
<?php
$description = strip_tags($_POST['description']);
?>
<img src="" alt="<?php echo $description ?>" title="<?php echo $description ?>" data-description="<?php echo $description ?>" />
```

I find it hard to believe making a variable copy has more of a performance hit then:

```
<img src="" alt="<?php echo strip_tags($_POST['description']) ?>" title="<?php echo strip_tags($_POST['description']) ?>" data-description="<?php echo strip_tags($_POST['description']) ?>" />
```

So I guess the "for no reason" is relevant above?

Comment: The question is: does it really make any noticeable difference in your real world code, and is the change affecting readability/maintainability/chances of bugs?

Comment: The answer here is more complex because of the irregularities that PHP has under the cover. Ex. the copy-on-write behavior makes copying variables effortless unless you plan to write to them. Counter-intuitively referencing variables sounds like it's more optimal but it may actually end up copying the data because some functions such as strlen/count expect the value to be passed by value not by reference and copy them for you.

Comment: In relation to the other answers you received about premature optimization: if you have a huge array in the area of tens of thousands of (complex) objects with lot of data on them and you copy & write into the copy... maybe optimization is in order, otherwise, at the very small scale it really isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top of the google page you linked quotes Hoare's dictum `Premature optimization is the root of all evil`.

Unecessary copies (i've found) are usually there to make the code more readable. If you're making the code less readable and having a neglible impact on performance then this is a bad thing. If you're convinced that this piece of code is called often enough to make a difference (and you have profiled to confirm this) then go ahead.

As you noted the examples you point out actually do have a good reason in that you are saving on extra work. Again however if the code is that critical then profile the differences.

Answer (score 9):

If copying variables becomes a performance issue, then something is severely wrong with your application and you've got much bigger issues to worry about. In 99.99999% of cases, this will never be your bottle neck. Going out of your way to purposely avoid copying variables is an act of micro-optimization. Focus on writing clean readable code that makes sense instead of worrying about small micro-optimizations like this. The Google article in question has actually received a lot of criticism in the past as it looks as though it was quickly thrown together by somebody who was grabbing random information from other random misinformed articles.

Comment: I totally agree there are many other factors to consider and worry about but when you get deeper into the details and bigger applications I think following bad advice (the Google article IMO) can eventually create performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood the article you are linking. with no offense.
For your example:

```
<img src="" alt="<?php echo strip_tags($_POST['description']) ?>" title="<?php echo strip_tags($_POST['description']) ?>" data-description="<?php echo strip_tags($_POST['description']) ?>" />
```

In this case you are calling strip_tags 3 times. Of course is sick and useless and is better to copy the result.
Because if compiled "strip_tags" in php has a "kill a puppy" statement, you are killing 3 instead of one :(

google example was:

```
$description = strip_tags($_POST['description']);
echo $description;
```

one time use.

And i would say, if you have to call a function 2 times and get same result, is better to copy.
code readability improves sometimes with copying, but this is not the topic.

I add my personal experience on performance:
using multidimensional associative array in loops sometimes has been a performance hit on loop of thousands of iteration ( less than hundred thousands ).
Copying the variable in a simple one and then using it on the loop was lot faster.
I cannot provide number of this experience anymore.

Comment: "I think you misunderstood the article you are linking. with no offense." Not at all. You are saying exactly what im saying? My point is that the Google statement should have an extra condition to it saying dont make a single copy for single use. If there is processing on the variable then im guessing performance will actually improve by making a copy of the processed result.

Comment: ok i'm sorry!i should not say misunderstood, but took it too literally ( if is irght in english ). Yes they should add a statement, but is not a article for everyone, maybe this statament was in the middle of each line. At the end is an article intended for developers.